# No se registra dato tipo decimal en la BD

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy intentanto registrar un record con un campo de tipo decimal, con un modelo de datos Entity Framework, utilizzo un objeto para valorizar los campo, los veo todos con valores pero cuando ejecuta el metodo **_DbModelEntities.SaveChanges();**  en la base de dato se registran todos los campo excepto el campo de la cantidad que aparece con NULL.

El objeto valoriado :

```
       public bool Movimenta(oMovimenta movimenta)
    {

        log_Operazioni operazione = new log_Operazioni()
        {
            MVCODART = movimenta.CodArt,
            MVCODUBI = movimenta.Ubica,
            MVCODUTE = movimenta.CodUte,
            MVTIPMOV = movimenta.Tipo,
            MVQTAMOV = (decimal)movimenta.QtaMov,
            MVDATMOV = DateTime.Now,
            MVCODCOM = movimenta.commessa


        };
```

en SQL veo la instrucion sin el campo MVQTAMOV

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[log_Operazioni]([MVCODART], [MVCODUBI], [MVCODUTE], 
[MVDATMOV], [MVTIPMOV], [MVCODCOM])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT [ID]
FROM [dbo].[log_Operazioni]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ID] = scope_identity()',N'@0 varchar(40),@1 varchar(2),@2 int,@3 datetime2(7),@4 varchar(1),@5 nvarchar(15)',@0='PAN',@1='US',@2=1,@3='2022-02-19 23:23:40.5835822',@4='V',@5=N'TEST'
```

- 

Cree la base separada y luego cargue el modelo a partir de la definicion en sql, la estructura sigue aqui

```
CREATE TABLE log_Operazioni (
ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
MVCODART varchar(40) NOT NULL,
MVCODUBI varchar(2) NOT NULL,
MVCODUTE int NOT NULL,
MVDATMOV DATETIME,
MVTIPMOV varchar(1) NOT NULL,
MVCODCOM nvarchar(15)  NOT NULL,
MVQTAMOV decimal(12,3), 
FOREIGN KEY (MVCODART) REFERENCES Articoli(ARCODART),
FOREIGN KEY (MVCODUTE) REFERENCES Utenti(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (MVCODCOM) REFERENCES Com_essa(CNCODCOM)
```

);

El Campo en question es **MVQTAMOV decimal(12,3),**

les dejo el link al projecto

[projecto](https://github.com/NorisD/DemoStesi)

Que podria esta pasando? gracias

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu modelo?, ¿tu base la creaste desde código o de forma separada?, si la creaste de forma separada también puedes compartirnos la estructura que tiene

Comment: Y cual es tu campo de tipo float, revisa bien debes dar todos los detalles para que se te pueda ayudar

Answer (score 1):

A pesar que la clase de la entidad mostrata la propiedad que correspondia al campo, el diagrama del modelo non mostraba, lo reslvì actualizando el modelo de la tabla desde el **edmx.diagram**